# How do I read/write both xlsx and xls files in Python?

Tags: python, xlrd, openpyxl

I have a web application (based on Django 1.5) wherein a user uploads a spreadsheet file.

I've been using `xlrd` for manipulating xls files and looked into `openpyxl` which claims to support xlsx/xlsm files.

So is there a common way to read/write both xls and xlsx files?

Another option could be to convert the uploaded file to xls and use `xlrd`. For this I looked into `gnumeric` and `ssconvert`, this would be favorable since all my existing code in written using xlrd and I will not have to change the existing codebase.

So should I change the library I use or go with the conversion solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check whether xlwings suits your purpose. (http://xlwings.org/)

Answer (score 1):

xlrd can read both xlsx and xls files, so it's probably simplest to use that. Support for xlsx isn't as extensive as openpyxl but should be sufficient.

There's a risk of losing information in converting xlsx to xls because xlsx files can be much larger.

Comment: When I used xlrd to parse my xlsx files, it threw an assertion error, essentially ruling out xlrd.

Comment: I don't know much about xlrd. You might be able to work around the assertion error if you run Python in optimised mode. You might want to submit a bug. though a pull request would be better.

You could try running the files through a headless OpenOffice to normalise them to one format or the other.

Otherwise you'll probably have to use both libraries. The APIs are similar but do differ in some important areas: notably that openpyxl uses 1-indexing.

Comment: Turns out openpyxl is not compatible with xls files, I guess conversion is my best bet for the time being, I will have to port the xlrd code to openpyxl someday though.

Comment: openpyxl has never been, and probably never will be, compatible with xls files.

Comment: I use xlrd to parse both .xls and .xlsx all the time. If you are getting an error, you should ask for help on the mailing list and give the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [xlrd's CHANGES](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html), they dropped support for `.xlsx` files as of version `2.0` (since 2010).
2. A quick look at [python-excel.org](https://www.python-excel.org) list finds that there are still no tools supporting both formats (in 2023).

The imho simplest solution is to roll back to `xlrd` version `1.x`, that may still be acceptable if the newest Excel features are not planned to be supported.